# Count based on a Conditions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, union

I would like to get the levels counted

**Input**

```
|id|levels|
|--| --- |
|1 |9    |
|2 |12   |
|3 |21   |
|4 |23   |
|5 |11   |
|6 |31   |
|7 |23   |
|8 |11   |
|9 |31   |
```

**Expected output**

```
|range        |count|
|-------------|-----|
|more than 10 | 8   |
|more than 20 | 5   |
|more than 30 | 2   |
```

Currently, I am writing queries individually to get the count the levels greater than 10,20, and 30. But how can I get them all in a single instance?

Comment: ill defined as we can't guess what you are counting, as the posting guidelines suggest, showing what you have done to try solving your question may help with that

Comment: The accepted answer does not match the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thew most efficient method should be aggregation with a cumulative sum:

```
select (case when levels > 10 then 'more than 10'
             when levels > 20 then 'more than 20'
             when levels > 30 then 'more than 30'
        end) as range,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(levels)) as count
from t
where levels > 10
group by range;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want 1 row for each range then use 3 different queries and `UNION ALL` for the final result:

```
SELECT 'more than 10' AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tablename WHERE levels > 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'more than 20' AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tablename WHERE levels > 20
UNION ALL
SELECT 'more than 30' AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tablename WHERE levels > 30
```

It would be easier to get the result in 1 row with 3 columns with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(levels > 10) AS `more than 10`, 
       SUM(levels > 20) AS `more than 20`,
       SUM(levels > 30) AS `more than 30`
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab644a35d84929bd247dbe74497e9fb0).

Answer (score 2):

I would build a table of ranges and join with it

```
SELECT CONCAT('greater than ', n) AS range, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM (
SELECT 10 AS n UNION ALL
SELECT 20 AS n UNION ALL
SELECT 30 AS n
) AS r
INNER JOIN your_table ON level >= n
GROUP BY n
```